# using session storage to store user position

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I have a [one page application](https://d29o1kaag89e5d.cloudfront.net/) that I wrote using mostly vanilla js.
Because is an one page application, when a user reload the page it start from the beginning, so I'm wondering if there is a way to use session storage to save user position in the page. So when he refresh the page, the position remains the last one.

The page works like that: when a user click one of the main button, the item get the class `active` and is content is expanded to all the screen, the body also get the class `has-expanded-item` and all his children that doesn't have the class active disappear.

This is the code that handle the menu switching:

```
class BoxLayout{
  constructor(menuVoices,buttonHandler){
    this.wrapper = document.body;
    this.menuVoices = menuVoices;
    this.closeButtons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.close-section'));
    this.expandedClass = 'is-expanded';
    this.hasExpandedClass = 'has-expanded-item';
    this.buttonHandler = buttonHandler;
    this.init()
  }

  init(){
    this._initEvents()
  }

  _initEvents(){
    let self = this;
    this.menuVoices.forEach(function(el){
      el.addEventListener('click',function(){
          self._openSection(this) //this fn give to the element the class active
          self.buttonHandler.disable(this,this.nextElementSibling)
      });
    });
    this.closeButtons.forEach(function(el){
      el.addEventListener('click',function(el){
        el.stopPropagation();
        self._closeSection(this.parentElement)
        self.buttonHandler.enable(this.nextElementSibling)
      })
    });
  }

  _openSection(el){
    if(!el.parentElement.classList.contains(this.expandedClass)){
      el.parentElement.classList.add(this.expandedClass);
      this.wrapper.classList.add(this.hasExpandedClass)
    }
  }

  _closeSection(el){
    if(el.classList.contains(this.expandedClass)){
      el.classList.remove(this.expandedClass);
      this.wrapper.classList.remove(this.hasExpandedClass)
    }
  }
}
```

now when i click on, for instance, the about section, the parent element of the about button get the active class, i want to save the state in a session storage but i dont know how to do, first time I'm using this api

Comment: Questions about code on Stack Overflow require the code to be on this website. It's not clear that you're asking about the code on this other site. Is there some specific question you had about working with `sessionStorage`? Otherwise this question is quite vague.

Comment: I update the question, hope is more clear

Comment: Not an answer, but `classList` has a `toggle` function that will add or remove the class depending on its presence, so you wouldn't need the `contains`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now i found this solution using session storage, giving for each section a data attribute, but could be also an id:

```
 _openSection(el){
    el.parentElement.classList.toggle(this.expandedClass);
    this.wrapper.classList.add(this.hasExpandedClass);
    sessionStorage.setItem('section',el.parentElement.dataset.section)
}
```

in the main js:

```
const sections = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.section'));  
if(sessionStorage.length){
      sections.forEach(function(section){
        if(section.dataset.section === sessionStorage.getItem('section')){
          section.classList.add('is-expanded')
          document.body.classList.add('has-expanded.item')
        }
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use session-storage or simply a client-side cookie, but that will not allow bookmarking, sharing links, or history to work as the user might expect. The best option, in my opinion, is using links like `example.com/index.php#experience` or, using history.pushState();

```
function rewrite(page){
    var stateObj = { index: page };
    history.pushState(stateObj, page, page+".html");
}
```

If `example.com/index.html` executes `rewrite("experience")`, the browser will change the address bar to `example.com/experience.html` without refreshing the page.

This technique can allow bookmarking and the like once you redirect `experience.html` to something like `index.html?experience`, which your script handles by rewriting the URL. If you have any server-side experience, you could very easily write a URL rewriting script.

## Simple rewriting thing

#### experience.html

`location.href('index.html?experience')`

#### index.html

```
function rewrite(page){
        var stateObj = { index: page };
        history.pushState(stateObj, page, page+".html");
}

rewrite(window.location.search.substr(1));//Grab page from querystring
```

Comment: The [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) in the browser has nothing to do with cookies or anything server-side.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You are right, I was confused with the server side idea of sessions, which are commonly persisted with a client-side cookie

Comment: thanks but there is no server-side code to handle the app

Comment: @LimeInTheCoconut You don't need any server side code, that's what the last paragraph or so is about, a pure-javascript solution

Comment: ok but i have only one index.hml file, not an experience.html about.html etc

Comment: @LimeInTheCoconut Make an HTML file with that name, stick the one line in a script, and it should work great

Comment: ok i create the experience.html page and insert the one line script, then i insert the function rewrite into index.html, but when i reload the page i get this error: Cannot GET /.html , for now i'm testing with development server in node

Comment: @LimeInTheCoconut I forgot, you need to wrap the function call in an if statement like this `if (location.search!==""){rewrite(window.location.search.substr(1));}`

Comment: doesnt' work, i found a solution using session storage, thanks anyway